# How to generate html files from web application?

Tags: java, mockups

I have a existing java web application. Whenever there are changes to enhance the application. What we usually do is that we will take the screenshots of the page and use some image editor software to copy and paste the modified design e.g. add new fields etc. and then send to users for review.

I like to ask if there is anyway to generate the html mockup from the web application? Such that we can directly edit from the mockup instead.

I know we can use wget but my application is password protected so i not sure which command to use.

Will appreciate for more advice thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
wget --user=username --password='password' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/?ref=adwords&campaign=general-search&adgroup=mockup-software&ad=004&gclid=CNafsubTpasCFUje4AodOg9F2Q) is what you have in mind.

Comment: Does Balsamiq **generate the html mockup from the web application**? User wants the new mock-ups to be modifications of the existing system.